# What are the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix $A=\Big(\frac{1}{\cos(k-l)\frac{\pi}{n}}\Big)_{k,l=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ when $n$ is odd?

Tags: eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector, toeplitz-operators, circulant-matrices

Suppose that $n$ is odd.  The eigen values/eigenvectors of the skew-circulant  matrix $A=\Big(\frac{1}{\cos(k-l)\frac{\pi}{n}}\Big)_{k,l=1}^n$  are successfully computed in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437212/the-eigenvalues-of-the-matrix-big-frac1-cosk-l-frac-pin-big-k-l-1).

Q.  What are  the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the sub-matrix $B=\Big(\frac{1}{\cos(k-l)\frac{\pi}{n}}\Big)_{k,l=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$?

p.s. If not all eigenvalues of $B$ can be analytically determined, the smallest and largest ones are also helpful.

Comment: If you increase the dimension by $1$, then the largest eigenvalue would be $n$ by the Cauchy interlacing theorem. If you increase the dimension by $2$, then you also get that the smallest would be $-n$ for the same reason. But for this case, it doesn't seem like there's a good characterization. You can potentially get bounds using standard techniques, i.e. Courant-Fischer.

Comment: You have a symmetric Toeplitz matrix. There is some literature on their eigenvalues but I don't know if it applies well to your problem. [This](http://www.netlab.tkk.fi/julkaisut/tyot/erikoistyot/matkapuh/42687R.pdf) might give pointers but beware as it looks like a student project.

Comment: Any suggestion to get the value of the norm of $B$? (I mean the operator norm of $B$ when it operates on the real Hilbert space  $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an operator.